# Eloquent - Store serialized arrays in database - Method overwriting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a model `user` in my database that has a column containing a serialized string `contact`.

My question is: is it possible to ovewrite the method `getContactAttribute` in order to directly output unserialized data?

Comment: Create a class `userRaw` which extends `user`, create the method `userRaw::getContactAttribute` which does what you want with the raw data?

Comment: @N.B. that's a pretty good idea indeed. Do you think it is possible to avoid creating a new class, using for example model observers? I've noticed them in the documentation. Thanks anyway for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is totally possible, check this section of documentation:

[Laravel 4.2 Docs Accessors and Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Well, that's interesting. For some reason, this did not work at some point in my code, but the (trivial) solution seems to be good! Thanks!